# Reading Excel file , getting single row in an array in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a old excel file , i want to modify that.

i need to filter rows from my old excel file and write selected rows to new excel file.

My plan is to read a single row,store it in a list,pass this arraylist to a function.

The function does some checking on the arraylist, if the condition is satisfied, i will write this entire row to my new excel file else i will go back and read next row.

I am not getting anything to read a single row and save it in a arraylist.

I am able to read cell by cell and do conditioning , but this is very slow.

Any better option.

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire input file into a custom-made object at the same time, do your work on it, then write all of that data at the same time into the final Excel file at the same time.